# Macro defining macro

Tags: macros

I have the following:

```
\newcommand{\makeWord}[1]{%
\newcommand{\#1}{\textrm{#1}}}

\makeWord{AdditiveGroup}
\newcommand{\AdditiveGroup}{\textrm{AdditiveGroup}}
```

Unfortunately, I did not properly define the makeWord macro. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\makeWord}[1]{%
\newcommand{\#1}{\textrm{#1}}}
```

`\#1` is the two tokens `\#` (which would typeset a `#`) and `1` so is a syntax error as the first argument of `\newcommand`.

Try

```
\newcommand{\makeWord}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{\textrm{#1}}}
```

Note this will make a mathord token if used in math. If you want to make an operator like `\log` it needs to be

```
\newcommand{\makeWord}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{\mathop{\mathrm{#1}}}}
```

or use the `amsopn`  `\DeclareMathOperator`  command.