# How to create a command that creates commands?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, key-value

I recently learned how to make `key=value` commands with the `pgfkeys` package. I'm currently trying to define a command, let's call it `\commander`, with `key=value` options that can define new commands also with `key=value` functions. (Something like supercommand or metacommand.) The syntax of `\commander` is roughly the following:

```
\commander[color=red,pos=up,invert=false]{\thenewcommand}
```

Our `\thenewcommand` is expected to have some (but not all) of the same `key=value` options of `\commander`; furthermore, their default values have to be the values called by `\commander` (or the default values of `\commander` if they aren't explicitly called). For example, if `\thenewcommand` is defined as above, then calling:

```
\thenewcommand[color=blue]
```

is just the same as calling:

```
\thenewcommand[color=blue,pos=up,invert=false]
```

I have made some steps towards defining `\commander`. Here are its `pgfkeys`.

```
\newif\ifcommanderinvert
\pgfkeys{
    /commander/.is family, /commander,
    % "commander" options
    color/.estore in = \commanderColor,
    pos/.estore in = \commanderPos,
    invert/.is if=commanderinvert,
    % Ignore this: It is just for showing that I'm using the .unknown feature
    .unknown/.code={\edef\commanderUnk{\commanderUnk,\pgfkeyscurrentname=#1}},%
}
```

And here is an incomplete definition of `\commander`:

```
% (Optional) argument #1 is for the options
% (Non-optional) argument #2 is the name of the new command
%                                    (e.g.: \thenewcommand)
\newcommand{\commander}[2][]{%
% Loading \commander's pgfkeys
\pgfkeys{/commander,%
    color=black,%
    pos=up,%
    invert=false,#1}%
%
% Here goes some code 
Code...
%
% Here I define the pgfkeys for \thenewcommand.
% Every appearance of the string "thenewcommand" has to be replaced
% by the actual name of our new command or an abbreviation.
% Else, we risk making conflicting names each time we call \commander.
\newif\ifthenewcommandinvert
\pgfkeys{
    /thenewcommand/.is family, /thenewcommand,
    % "thenewcommand" options
    % Notice I'm not using the "pos" option
    color/.estore in = \thenewcommandColor,
    invert/.is if=thenewcommandinvert,
}
% Defining \thenewcommand: it only has optional arguments
% Notice that the name of the new command is #2 of \commander
\newcommand{#2}[1][]{%
\pgfkeys{/thenewcommand,%
    color=\commanderColor,%
    %invert=?,
    % How do I pass here the value of /commander invert/?
    #1}%
% Here goes some code
\ifthenewcommandinvert%
    Code...%
\else%
    Code...\fi%
% (By the way, how can I distinctly refer to
% argument #1 of \commander and to argument #1 of \thenewcommand?)
}
```

With a definition along these lines, if we call `\commander` as follows:

```
\commander[color=blue]{\bluecommand}
```

then calling:

```
\bluecommand[invert=true]
```

must be the same as calling:

```
\bluecommand[color=blue,pos=up,invert=true]
```

In order to complete this function I have to overcome two challenges:

1. What is the best strategy for recursively creating the `pgfkeys` for each new command created with `\commander`?
2. How do I the pass value of the `invert` key of `\commander` as the default value of the `invert` key of the new command.

I hope someone can give me some hand here. Thanks in advance.

PS: For this command I'm using/requiring the packages `graphicx`, `pgfkeys` and `tikz` and, optionally, the class `beamer`.

Comment: Potential duplicate ? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65781/141947

Comment: Thanks, @BambOo. I don't think it's a duplicate. The use of key=value options takes this into another level. It is still useful, though.

Comment: You can do this with `\csname <command name>\endcsname` but given that you are using pgf keys, why not just using `<my new command>/.code={<code>}`. This would also allow you to store the other keys on a directory of that name. (`graphicx` gets loaded by `tikz`.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll test your answer.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I didn't have time to properly read your answer until now. I don't understand what you mean by "why not just using `<my new command>/.code={<code>}`". I suppose since I am new in `pgfkeys`, I don't have the proper background to understand what you say. (E.g. I don't know where to write that code.) Maybe you can point me to some part of the manual. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I meant is that, as explained in section **87.1.2 Quick Guide to Using the Key Mechanism** of pgfmanual v3.14b. you can also use pgf keys to "execute" some code. I do not understand the purpose of "invert" and other things, otherwise I could post an example.

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger'scat, the command created is for processing graphics. The `pos` is for determinig the position, `color` is for coloring the image, and `invert` is for inverting the colors. I didn't post the whole code because it is somewhat big (specially considering it depends on some other commands previously defined.)

Comment: The thing is that internally pgf keys work by using `\csname <command name>\endcsname` to convert keys to macros, which they internally use. You in a way seem to aim at "inverting" this procedure. Which is why I would suggest just to work with pgf keys, and `/.code`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer provides two code versions, one using `expkv-cs`, one using `pgfkeys`-only.

### Using `expkv-cs`

The following could be used for this, but circumvents much of the expansion problems of using `pgfkeys` for `\commander` by using `expkv-cs`. The advantage is that as long as you're using simple macros with only few keys the `\ekvcSplit`-approach provides you with the values of your keys as they were given by the user as macro parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\commander[1][]{\commander@k{#1}}
\newif\ifcommander@invert
\ekvcSplitAndForward\commander@k\commander@d
  {
     color = black
    ,pos = up
    ,invert = false
  }
\pgfqkeys{/commander}%
  {%
    .is family
    ,color/.store in = \commander@color
    ,pos/.store in = \commander@pos
    ,invert/.is if=commander@invert
    ,.unknown/.code=%
      {\edef\commander@unk{\commander@unk,\pgfkeyscurrentname={##1}}}%
  }
\newcommand\commander@d[4]
  {%
    \newcommand#4[1][]
      {%
        \begingroup
          \pgfqkeys{/commander}{color={#1},pos={#2},invert={#3},##1}%
          \ifcommander@invert
            \commander@color\space code being inverted at \commander@pos
          \else
            \commander@color\space code at \commander@pos
          \fi
        \endgroup
      }%
  }
\makeatother

\commander[color=blue]\thenewcommand
\commander[invert=true]\thenewcommandinvert

\begin{document}
\thenewcommand

\thenewcommand[color=green,invert=false]

\thenewcommandinvert

\thenewcommandinvert[color=green,invert=false]
\end{document}
```

---

### Using only `pgfkeys`

This version uses a temporary definition `\commander@tmp` that helps expanding the current values of your keys.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\commander[2][]
  {%
    \begingroup
    \pgfqkeys{/commander}{#1}%
    \edef\commander@tmp % <- shouldn't be used by a key
      {%
        \endgroup
        \unexpanded{\newcommand#2[1][]}%
          {%
            \begingroup
            \unexpanded{\pgfqkeys{/commander}}%
              {%
                 color={\unexpanded\expandafter{\commander@color}}%
                ,pos={\unexpanded\expandafter{\commander@pos}}%
                ,invert=\ifcommander@invert true\else false\fi
                ,####1%
              }%
            \unexpanded{\commander@code}%
            \endgroup
          }%
      }%
    \commander@tmp
  }
\newcommand\commander@code
  {%
    \ifcommander@invert
      \commander@color\space code being inverted at \commander@pos
    \else
      \commander@color\space code at \commander@pos
    \fi
  }
\newif\ifcommander@invert
\pgfqkeys{/commander}%
  {%
    .is family
    ,color/.store in = \commander@color
    ,color=black
    ,pos/.store in = \commander@pos
    ,pos=up
    ,invert/.is if=commander@invert
    ,invert=false
    ,.unknown/.code=%
      {\edef\commander@unk{\commander@unk,\pgfkeyscurrentname={##1}}}%
  }
\makeatother

\commander[color=blue]\thenewcommand
\commander[invert=true]\thenewcommandinvert

\begin{document}
\thenewcommand

\thenewcommand[color=green,invert=false]

\thenewcommandinvert

\thenewcommandinvert[color=green,invert=false]
\end{document}
```

---

### Output of both

[image]